# How to change Vim's :hardcopy printfont?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, macvim, font, printing

I would like to be able to print in other than Courier font using the `:ha` command.

Investigating more closely, I found that it is documented that the Courier font is always used:

> ```
> - 'printfont' - The font name is ignored (the Courier family is always used -
>   it should be available on all PostScript printers) but the font size is
>   used.
> ```

— From `:help postscript-printing`

However, there must be some workaround, perhaps using an external tool.

I would like to keep my Vim syntax highlighting in the printout, which rules out just opening the file in TextEdit (or TextWrangler) for printing.

I'm using MacVim snapshot 73, which is Vim 7.4.258.

How can I print a file to PDF using Vim's syntax highlighting but an alternate font?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of printing from Vim, you could instead generate an HTML file using [`:TOhtml`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#:TOhtml).  Then you can use CSS to set the font used for the HTML and print that.

Comment: This answer is amazing. Been using vi since the 80s, and vim since it came out, never knew about this. Even carries utf-8 content over to the html.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know when it changed, but now **it's possible.**

For example:

```
:set printfont=Fira_Code:h12
:hardcopy
```

do the job.
I'm using Vim 9 on Windows.

(P.S. I will try with MacVim in a few days and I'll update this answer.)